# jQuery hover function with toggle not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code that's supposed to toggle the background of a div and some p and it doesn't and I can't figure out why. Can you please help?

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.portfolio-img").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).toggleClass(".portfolio-img-hover");
            $(this).find("h5.excerpt-title").toggleClass(".excerpt-title-hover");
            $(this).find("p.portfolio-excerpt").toggleClass(".portfolio-excerpt-hover"); 
        }
      )
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="portfolio-img">
    <a href="#single_project"><img src="images/thumbnail.jpg"/></a>
    <h5 class="excerpt-title">First Title</h5>
    <p class="portfolio-excerpt">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum                Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
h5.excerpt-title{
    margin:30px 0px 5px;
    transition:background-color 0.5s ease;
}

.excerpt-title-hover{
    opacity:1;
    color: #ed0b0b;
}

.portfolio-excerpt-hover{
    opacity:1;
    background:#e2e2e2;
}

.portfolio-img-hover{
    opacity:1;
    background:#e2e2e2;
    border-bottom:2px solid #ed0b0b;
}

.portfolio-img{
    width:220px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:15px 5px;
    margin:0px 5px 10px;
    opacity:0.6;
    border-bottom:1px solid grey;
    transition:background-color 0.5s ease;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/a12b0u0k/

Comment: A) you need to remove the tag and the dot in the toggle class function. B) you need to add the dot in the find function : http://jsfiddle.net/a12b0u0k/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your jQuery to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("div.portfolio-img").hover(function(){
         $(this).toggleClass("portfolio-img-hover");
         $(this).find("h5.excerpt-title").toggleClass("excerpt-title-hover");
         $(this).find("p.portfolio-excerpt").toggleClass("portfolio-excerpt-hover"); 
      }
   );
});
```

and swap places on your `.portfolio-img-hover{}` and `portfolio-img{}` in your css.

Try it out here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yanuk8fL/)

Comment: Hey, so I've done it like it's in the fiddle and it's not woring, do you know why? Thanks and here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tyfwvvnh/1/

Comment: You have no jQuery in your fiddle. You can add it in the left hand side menu, Frameworks & Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).toggleClass("div.portfolio-img-hover");`

`div.portfolio-img-hover` is a selector. You just want `portfolio-img-hover`.

`toggleClass` will add/remove whatever you put inside the `()`, and you want to add `portfolio-img-hover` not the `div.` part.

Comment: It's still not working...can you show it to me in the fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the toggle class method you should only include the class name, like below.
You should also store `$(this)` in a variable.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div.portfolio-img").hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass("portfolio-img-hover");
    $this.find("h5.excerpt-title").toggleClass("excerpt-title-hover");
    $this.find("p.portfolio-excerpt").toggleClass("portfolio-excerpt-hover"); 
  })
});
```

Additionally, you want to make sure your "hover" class styling is below the default styling in your CSS, and you should really include the original selector as well.

See here http://jsfiddle.net/a12b0u0k/1/